# Can't retrieve numeric input and assign it to a variable

Tags: php, variables, input

I'm tring to retrieve the numeric input and store it in the variabe q but I can't seem to access it using the method post this way.

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produit";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

?>
<div class="prod<?php echo $row['ID_produit']?>">
<img src="images/<?php echo $row['image']?>" alt="image">
<h3><?php echo $row['nom_produit']?></h3>
<h3>Prix:<?php echo $row['prix']?>&euro;</h6>
<form action="" method="post">
<label name="qte">QTE:</label>
<input type="number" name="qte"><br><br>

<a href="panier.php?action=ajout&amp;
l=<?php echo $row['nom_produit']?>&amp;
q=<?php $_POST['qte']?>&amp;
p=<?php echo $row['prix']?>" 
onclick="window.open(this.href, '', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=yes, 
scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width=600, height=350'); return false;">
GOGOGO  </a>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
 </div>
```

I also tried with

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $example = $_POST['qte'];
 echo $example;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: q=<?php $_POST['qte']?>? is this all happening after a form submission? Or are you trying to get the value of that input element when you click the GOGO link?

Comment: @Kinglish After i click on the GOGO link I'm sent on another page where it shows me the value I want for the variable l and p but not for q. Though when I give q a set value, like 2, it works.

Comment: There's no submit button on that form, `$_POST['qte']` is most likely never set

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple issues with this code. You were trying to reference `qte` in each loop through a `$_POST` variable, when what you really wanted was to just grab the input from the user. In an effort to clean up the code a little and make things more readable, I changed that big `<a href...` tag to trigger a function that will grab the `qte` value, form the URL and open the window. Note that I pass into the function the `productID` and `prix` values. I put them in quotes just in case they're blank. I also added an `ID` to your `qte input` element so we can get the value. Take a look and let me know if you need clarification

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produit";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){    
?>
<div class="prod<?php echo $row['ID_produit']?>">
<img src="images/<?php echo $row['image']?>" alt="image">
<h3><?php echo $row['nom_produit']?></h3>
<h3>Prix:<?php echo $row['prix']?>&euro;</h6>
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
<label for="qte">QTE:</label>
<input type="number" name="qte" id="qte_<?php echo $row['ID_produit']?>"><br><br>

<a href='javascript:void(0)' 
  onclick='gogoLink("<?php echo $row['ID_produit']?>", "<?php echo $row['prix']?>")'>
GOGOGO  </a>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>

// then outside the loop is the function 

<script>
function gogoLink(id, prix) {
  let url ="panier.php?action=ajout"
  url += "&l=" + id
  url += "&q=" + document.getElementById("qte_"+id).value;
  url += "&p=" + prix;

  window.open(url, '', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=yes, 
  scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, copyhistory=no, width=600, height=350'); 
}
</script>
```